# Unity. Как перебрать и вызывать метод дочерних объектов с разными скриптами?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть тайловая пошаговая игра в Unity. После хода противников, я хочу перебирать все дочерние объекты (ловушки) в объекте, где хранятся ловушки. Дело в том, что разные ловушки работают по разному, соответственно, имеют разные скрипты и разные методы, в том числе метод проверки, должна ли ловушка активироваться.

Вопрос в том, как можно перебирать объекты ловушек и вызывать их методы проверки, если у них разные скрипты.

Comment: почитать информацию про наследование и интерфейсы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полиморфизм же.

К примеру есть интерфейс и метод:

```
interface ITile
{
   void Apply(Player player);
}
```

И коллекция этих интерфейсов

```
public ITile[] tiles;
```

И есть всякие разные классы, реализующие этот интерфейс

```
class Trap : ITile
{
    void Apply(Player player)
    {
        player.speed = 0;
    }
}

class Bonus : ITile
{
    void Apply(Player player)
    {
        player.money += 100;
    }
}
```

Тогда получится вот такой код

```
tiles = new ITile[2];
tiles[0] = new Trap();
tiles[1] = new Bonus();
```

К примеру игрок пришел на клетку, он не знает что там.

```
tiles[position].Apply(this);
```

То есть встречный эффект от тайла будет зависеть от того, что там внутри за скрипт сидит, но активируются все скрипты одинаково.

Comment: Спасибо большое!